# Write output of QGIS Batch Processing to temporary layers

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, layers, memory-layer, batch

Is it possible to write the outputs of QGIS Batch Processing to temporary/memory layers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is. You must use the keyword
`TEMPORARY_OUTPUT`
in the field that sets the output location.

Don't forget to check *Load layers on completion* then!

[image]